# Adobe Document Language Setting Does Not Hold

Tags: pdf, language, adobe-acrobat

I have Adobe Acrobat X Pro.  I am trying to straighten up some language settings on PDFs for accessibility purposes.  I go into Adobe Acrobat, go into the document properties, change the document language and save.  If I reopen the document in Acrobat, it shows me that the language is still set to English.  However, if I open the document in Reader (have tried Readers X, XI and DC for good measure) the language doesn't show that it's set.  The utility that we use to scan for accessibility issues also still does not detect the language.  Is there something else that needs to be done in order for this language setting to be recognized in all applications?